# How to list all running VirtualBox machines?

Tags: virtualbox

There are a number of users on this Ubuntu box. Most of them have a vbox machine started by themselves from their login.
And the command:

> VBoxManage list runningvms

lists only the vms for the user that runs it. 
Is there a way I can get a list of all running VirtualBox machines?

Maybe a script that can run the  command above for each user on the system?

Comment: use sudo `sudo VBoxManage.... ` or `ps aux | grep VirtualBox` or grep whatever the  name of the running VBox binary / process or `top`.